# Validity of $\exists x \forall y: x \le y$ in set of integers and set of natural numbers

Tags: logic, quantifiers

If I say $\exists x\in \mathbb{N} $ such that $\forall y \in \mathbb{N},$ $x \leq y$, this is a true statement. I am assuming that the set of natural numbers is defined for $0\leq x < \infty $.

But if I say the same thing for the set of all integers:
$\exists x\in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $\forall y \in \mathbb{Z},$ $x \leq y$ is a false statement, and I need help with my wording here: It is false because there does not exist an integer $x$ such that there are no integers less than $x$.

Am I correct in my logic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The statement is saying that there is a smallest element. This is *true* for natural numbers, *false* for integers. [...] [Your] claims are correct.

-- Ted (in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434462/difference-between-set-of-integers-and-set-of-natural-numbers#comment2922225_1434474)).

Answer (score -2):

Well it seems that your logic is false but you have to say why do you think there is no such number as x. Cause it exists .

Comment: The answer in the back of the book claims it is false, I am just trying to make sure I understand why.

Comment: Wow which book is this? If you put x in natural numbers then it is false otherwise the statement is correct.

Comment: The statement is saying that there is a smallest element.  This is *true* for natural numbers, *false* for integers, not the other way around.  @Jabernet 's original claims are correct.

Comment: Thank you @Ted, I find my self still fumbling around for the best way to state certain things. I will have to remember "smallest element"